# email deleted on email client is still in the inbox on my iphone

Tags: iphone

when I delete email on my email client, these email remain on my iphone. How do I get the iphone to have the same email as the server?

Comment: Are you accessing your mailbox via IMAP or POP?

Comment: Well, I have 2 email accounts, a gmail account that seems to be imap, and a verizon account that seems to be POP.

Comment: And which account shows the problem (or are both impacted)?

Comment: I just tested this and it seems its the POP account that is retaining mail on the iPhone after deleting via my PC.

Comment: I tried this again on the gmail account and it didn't update on the iPhone (the first time I tried it, the update happened soon after I deleted the mail).

Answer (score 2):

POP mail servers do not synchronise their data between devices in the way IMAP does.

Each device will download any mail in the queue when asked & will not auto-delete anything, except for any set server timeout interval, which is adjustable from Mail on the Mac or from iDevice - Settings > Mail, Contacts… > [the email account] Advanced > Delete from Server…

Other than that, deletion once downloaded is manual, per device.